# Why does this not transition a jira to resolved?

Tags: python, api, rest, jira

```
updated_issue = jira.transition_issue(origin_issue.key,
                                                 '5',
                                                 {'id': 'Resolution',
                                                  'values': '6'}
                                                )
```

In this case I am talking to JIRA 5.1.5 through the jira-python library and their transition_jira method.
In this case '5' means resolve jira and '6' is the new status that updated jira will have '6' means DELIVERED ...

I try this code and the jira does not change the resolution field from unresolved to delivered

The error that I get is : u'Field \'id\' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.'

Why?

Comment: by the way I have Admin Jira credentials, which means that I can edit a JIRA and I have also followed the jira-python api convention on how to transit a jira issue .

Comment: did you solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following setup:

```
updated_issue = jira.transition_issue(origin_issue.key,
                                             '5',
                                             {'id': '6'}
                                            )
```

I've based on the recent [JIRA REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp1804224), which uses the following JSON Script:

```
{
"update": {
    "comment": [
        {
            "add": {
                "body": "Bug has been fixed."
            }
        }
    ]
},
"fields": {
    "assignee": {
        "name": "bob"
    },
    "resolution": {
        "name": "Fixed"
    }
},
"transition": {
    "id": "5"
}
```

}